# Determinant of 4x4 Matrix by Expansion Method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, laplace-expansion

Find **det(B)** = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 5 & -3 & -2 \\ -2 & -3 & 2 & -5 \\ 1 & 3 & -2 & 0 \\ -1 & -6 & 4 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}

I chose the 4th column because it has the most 0s. Using basketweave, I solved for the determinants of the minor 3x3 matrices of entry B<sub>14</sub> and B<sub>24</sub>.

**det(B<sub>14</sub>)** = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -3 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 & -2 \\ -1 & -6 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}

det(B<sub>14</sub>)
= (-24 - 6 - 12) - (-12 - 24 - 6)
= -42 - (-42)
= **0**

**det(B<sub>24</sub>)** = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 5 & -3 \\ 1 & 3 & -2 \\ -1 & -6 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}

det(B<sub>24</sub>)
= (24 + 10 + 18) - (20 + 24 + 9)
= 52 - 53
= **-1**

I have checked with a matrix calculator and the the determinants of the 3x3 minor matrices are correct.

To find the det(B), I multiplied B<sub>14</sub> by det(B<sub>14</sub>) and B<sub>24</sub> by det(B<sub>24</sub>) and followed the **+ - + -** pattern as showed by the formula [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-determinant.html) (scroll below for 4x4 formula). The rest will be 0s anyway.

**det(B)**
= [-2(0)] - [-5(-1)] + [0] - [0]
= **-5**

Checking again with the matrix calculator, the correct answer is **+5**.

I am confused as to how the signs apply. How did det(B) arrive to +5?

Comment: The formula changes its sign in subsequent rows. In the second row it goes -+-+..., so the sign on the $5$ should be "+".

Comment: How did you arrive to using the signs of the 2nd row?

Comment: When you added $\det(B_{24})$ in in your final equation, it should have $[-2(0)] + [-5(-1)] + [0] - [0]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern $+-+-$ works in the link you gave since they are expanding along the first row; it would be the same pattern when expanding along the first column. But then it changes as you change what column/row you're expanding along. For expanding along the second column it would be $-+-+$, along the third $+-+-$, and along the fourth $-+-+$.

Comment: Ah! So I should use the sign patterns of my chosen row or column. Since I chose the 4th column, the pattern should be - + - + which will yield -[-2(0)] + [-5(-1)] - [0] + [0]. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and the same pattern works if you choose different rows instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will confirm with a different row and a different column with their corresponding sign patterns. Marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The formula reads:
$$|A|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}M_{ij}$$
So the sign is positive/negative when the sum of the row index and the column index ($i+j$) is even/odd.