# How to find the value of a determinant using cofactors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How do I find the determinant of this matrix using expansion by cofactors?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2& 7& −1& 4\\
0& −5& 8& 11\\
0& 0& 3& −13\\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I understood how to do this with a smaller matrix but I'm not sure how to do it for a larger matrix like this.

Thank you

Comment: There is a simpler way to do this. The matrix is triangular so the determinant is the product of diagonal entries.

Comment: yes, but I'm trying to understand this technique.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize calculations, you want to expand the determinant along a row/column that has as many zeros as possible. For example, expanding along the first column, we have

$$ \det \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 7 & -1 & 4 \\ 0 & -5 & 8 & 11 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & -13 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} -5 & 8 & 11 \\ 0 & 3 & -13  \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} - 0\cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} 7 & -1 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 & -13 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\ + 
 0 \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} 7 & -1 & 4 \\ -5 & 8 & 11 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} - 0 \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} 7 & -1 & 4 \\ -5 & 8 & 11 \\ 0 & 3 & -13 \end{pmatrix} \\
= 2 \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} -5 & 8 & 11 \\ 0 & 3 & -13  \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}. $$

Doing the same for the resulting $3 \times 3$ matrix (that is, expanding along the first column), we get

$$ \det \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 7 & -1 & 4 \\ 0 & -5 & 8 & 11 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & -13 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} -5 & 8 & 11 \\ 0 & 3 & -13  \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = 2 \cdot (-5) \cdot \det \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -13 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$

and so on.

To make sure you understand the technique, try doing the calculation by expanding along the last row every time and see that you get the same answer ($-30$). Then to a random row/column expansion and verify that you still get the same answer.

Comment: Have you understood the rule of alternating signs ? If you are not sure have a look at (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/675292)